# Как создать иконку для своего приложения в меню фоновых приложений?

Tags: windows, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, уведомления

Никак не могу найти как создать маленькую иконку для моего приложения, как та, что у телеграмма, и других на скриншоте ниже.

[image: пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашёл рабочий пример, с объяснениями:

https://evileg.com/ru/post/68/